# Jenkins build error - Cannot run program "ant"

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have build.xml set up to run a project to execute selenium test cases. I have mac computer and I can run ant from terminal. But when I try to run from jenkins I get following error. I have specified Ant home in Jenkins' config

`/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.4/libexec`

I used homebrew to install ANT

`FATAL: command execution failed.Maybe you need to configure the job to choose one of your Ant installations?
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/BaublebarTest"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.processException(ProcessBuilder.java:478)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:457)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:802)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:380)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:387)
    at hudson.tasks.Ant.perform(Ant.java:217)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1754)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.`enter code here`forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Try setting your ant home to the root dir of the installation, e.g. /usr/local/Cellar/ant

Answer (score 11):

### First, the proper way

Jenkins will install Ant (and other tools for you). On the Global Configuration (Manage Jenkins), configure `Ant` installation, by selecting the version and the source.

Then, when you run an Ant build step, you can choose a version, either `default` or the one you've just configured. When the build is executed, Jenkins will download, install, and configure that particular version for you (**within Jenkins only**), without affecting the rest of the OS. The installation only needs to happen once per node, and after that it's quick.

### The `default`

That `default` version is a fallback that Jenkins uses when **you haven't configured** a proper version to use. It tries to use whatever is available on command line, simply by executing `ant` from current working directory.

You said it works for you when you just type `ant` on command line, but you've got to realize that Jenkins runs under `jenkins` user, not your logged in user, and things like `ANT_HOME` and proper path to Ant is probably configured specifically for your user.

So to fix your issue, either use the proper way with Jenkins doing the tool installation, or properly configure the tool on OS level for `jenkins` user.

You can start by typing:
`sudo su jenkins`
`ant`
And seeing if that works from within `jenkins` user

Comment: The issue with this is that if you have a customised installation of ant locally available (with custom jars etc.) the version installed automatically with Apache won't have them. Any build that needs the customised version will fail, so you should specify a custom installer that has those extras bundled. Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 7):

I am not using terminal for jenkins, but I was getting the same error. Changing Ant version from default to Ant fixed the errors.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what @slav was saying. Someone installed "Ant" from Global Tool Configuration, and you are here selecting it.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but people who are not using the terminal might still make use of this